# Using Sharepoint LoginName as parameter in datasource

Tags: sharepoint-designer, asp.net

This question was on StackOverflow, but I thought this would be a better place for it.

I am using asp:SqlDataSource to pull data and display this in a repeater control.

What I would like to do is use the Sharepoint LoginName as a parameter to add into my query but have been going round in circles trying to find out how to do this.

This control:

```
<asp:LoginName runat="server" id="LoginName1"></asp:LoginName>
```

Pulls the value that i need to use but I cannot seem to get this into the `<SelectParameters>` of my datasource.

I have also tried the `<asp:profileparameter>` but I am either not using it correctly or I need some extra config.

Comment: please delete the question on Stack Overflow, then. Don't post the same question on multiple sites.

Comment: StackOverflow question has been deleted.